# Where is missing UnixSocket class in dbus library?

Tags: scala, dbus

I am looking at using d-bus from Scala. I have added this to my `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ...
  "com.github.hypfvieh" % "dbus-java" % "3.0.2",
  ...
}
```

Building is find, but at runtime it can't find the `UnixSocket` class:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load library from any given source: [SYSTEM_PATH, CUSTOM_PATH, CLASS_PATH]
>       at com.github.hypfvieh.system.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:89)
>       at com.github.hypfvieh.system.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:69)
>       at cx.ath.matthew.unix.UnixSocket.(UnixSocket.java:54)

I've tried various artefacts on Maven that might have this class, but without success.

Is there another dependency I should be using, or do I need to add the appropriate library by hand?

Comment: Maybe `libraryDependencies += "com.github.jnr" % "jnr-unixsocket" % "0.23"`, from https://github.com/jnr/jnr-unixsocket/blob/master/src/main/java/jnr/unixsocket/UnixSocket.java

Comment: @MarioGalic Thanks for the suggestion. I did try that before, but no joy. The comment in github for dbus-java says that the version using  jnr-unixsocket (3.2.0) is not released yet. 3.0.2 is supposed to use `libmatthew` but I haven't found a suitable version of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the (old) dbus-java classes/libraries are on Maven, those bindings never used Maven as the buildsystem.  The original bindings can still be seen on the [dbus git repo](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/dbus/dbus-java/).

If you're on Debian, you should be able to get the libraries by running `apt-get install libunixsocket-java`.  If you are not on Debian or a Debian derivative, you would have to compile from [source](http://www.matthew.ath.cx/projects/java/).

Note that however the error that is happening is actually due to you not loading the JNI code library, that code is actually in the [dbus-java](https://github.com/hypfvieh/dbus-java/tree/dbus-java-parent-3.0.2/dbus-java/src/native) repo.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that is why the hypfvieh version is switching to `jnr-unixsocket` because that does appear to have a maven artefact. Next step is to work out how to build the source on Macos...

Comment: @Tim I just looked at the error again and I realized that the actual problem is you don't have the native code built(it can't find the .so file).  That code is in the dbus-java repo.